# How do I switch parent route but keeping child routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm sure there is a simple elegant solution for this Angular 4 routing problem.
I have the following routes - this is a master list with child views underneath:

```
/plan/:id/overview 
/plan/:id/details
... many more about 10 different child views
```

When I'm go to a particular route, say: 
`/plan/5` - this default me to `/plan/5/overview`

Then I switched to the details view `/plan/5/details`, but now selects a different plan `/plan/6`, how do I keep them on `/plan/6/details` currently my rules just default to `/plan/6/overview` this makes it hard for us to compare different plans quickly as it keeps resetting to the first child view.

My current route link looks like this:

```
[routerLink]="['plan/' + plan.Id ]" *ngFor="let plan of plans | async;"
```

Comment: How are you extracting the parameter from the route? Are you using it as [observable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#reuse)? Maybe that would help you to check the current state of your parent component to determine what child to show.

Comment: so on going to that route are you using the route id for making request or you are sending the data from the parent component `plan`

Comment: @elvin plans is an observable that's resolved at the top level `path:""`

:id is resolved at `plan/:id ` level and taken as a param.

I'm guess at the routerLink I could probably take the current children routes and attach them to the new route?  Is that the right idea?

Comment: @Aravind plans are resolved only once at the root route.  Child routes don't request Plans again.  So switching between plans only involves fetching additional child details, but not the root level plans list.  

Some child routes fetch their own additional resolves.  - I guess that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect like that with empty path.

```
let routes = [
  {
    path: "plan/:id",
    component: Plan,

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
        redirectTo: 'overview'
      },
      {
        path: "overview",
        component: Overview
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

here is full https://plnkr.co/edit/1xQcOyuEnTukBxCJtwzG

Comment: Hi - thank you - I actually have this redirect already - I'm more thinking about how to "not" redirect when I want to go to a different plan/:id and keep the existing child route "detail".

`[routerLink]="['plan/' + plan.Id + EXISTING-CHILD ]" `

Comment: it will be very misleading parent from new and overview from old. may be u do not need child-parent relationship but just siblings. like [{path: "plan/:id", component: Plan}, {path: "plan/:id/overview", component: Overview}